# Zend PDF and PHP: Drawn text has another position each time its drawn?

Tags: php, zend-pdf

I am using Zend PDF to draw text, like this:

```
$page->drawText('Hinweis: ' . $note, $this->getAlignCenter('Hinweis: ' . $note, 66, 100, $font, $fontSize), $this->y, 'UTF-8');
```

According to how long `$note` is, the text is placed somewhere else. How could I always align the complete text like 30px from the left border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAlignCenter()` calculates the position in which the text needs to be in order to be center aligned. If you simply want to left align it, provide the desired `x` coordinate instead of using `getAlignCenter()`.